# How to fix Illegal return statement error?

Tags: javascript

> It gives the Illegal return statement Error in my console, pertaining this part of the code ""*return message.reply("Missing Permissions!").then(m => m.delete(5000));*""

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}clear`){
  if (message.deletable) {
    message.delete();
  }

  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
  return message.reply("Missing Permissions!").then(m => m.delete(5000));
  }

  if (isNaN(args[0]) || parseInt(args[0]) <= 0) {
  return message.reply("This is not a number").then(m => m.delete(5000));
  }

  let deleteAmount;
  if (parseInt(args[0]) > 100) {
    deleteAmount = 100;
  } else {
    deleteAmount = parseInt(args[0]);
  }

  message.channel.bulkDelete(deleteAmount, true)
  .catch(err => message.reply(`Something went wrong... ${err}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code is not inside of a function, than you can't use `return`, as there is nothing to return it from: `return` can only be used inside of a function.